# get text node from strange html by selenium+python

Tags: python, dom, text, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i need to scrape phone number from this page for example - http://m.avito.ru/sankt-peterburg/muzykalnye_instrumenty/shesti_strunnoe_bandzho_stroy_gitarnyy_203671253

left blue button do this ajax request and return phone number not in innerText, but in separate text() node like this

```
<a href="tel:895**49****" class="button-text action-link" title="Телефон продавца" rel="nofollow">
"8 9** **9-99-**"
</a>
```

i click on this button. wait for a 3-5 seconds and try to get number
but i can't use **.text** like this

```
phone = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button-text')
print phone.text
```

it returns just an empty string
and when i try do this

```
print driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/article/section[2]/ul/li[1]/a/text()')
```

or this

```
print driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/article/section[2]/ul/li[1]/a/text()').text
```

it returns **InvalidSelectorException: Message: u'Error Message => \'The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/section/article/section[2]/ul/li[1]/a/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.**

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue the other day, and found out that the `text` method returns an empty string if the element is not visible. You can scroll to the element with javascript.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

Note: There are multiple elements with the `button-text` class on the page. If you want both of them in a list you could do something like:

```
phone = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('button-text')
phonenums = []
for p in phone:
    p.click()
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", p)
    phonenums.append(p.text)
```

However, if you're just trying to scrape pages like this I would try an entirely different approach. That page seems to be making no ajax requests, so you should be able to simply fetch the source with the `requests` library and parse that. If you do need/want to use Selenium, I'd have it grab the source (`source = driver.page_source`) and parse that with `lxml`.

I should also note that your final error is caused by calling the `text` method on a text node. I'm pretty sure Selenium can't retrieve text with `/text()` xpath's anyway.

Comment: oh, thank you but it isn't working too.. i don't know what way of protection they use, but it's realy annoying. i know about request, urlib2 and lxml, but for the time being i can't understand how it works)

Comment: Are you able to successfully fetch other text nodes from the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule for xpath:

```
print driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class, "button-text action-link")]/text()')
```

Demo:

```
In [3]: print sel.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "button-text action-link")]/text()').extract()[0]
Показать номер
```

Comment: returns **InvalidSelectorException: Message: u'Error Message => \'The result of the xpath expression '//a[contains(@class, "button-text action-link")]/text()' is: [object Text]. It should be an element.** too

Comment: As I see your link, we can't see the seller phone before we press the button "Показать номер". It means we can get seller's phone after we can semulity the press button.

Comment: ammm... i wrote about it in my question, and i simulate click, and cant scrape number after it.